# how to resolve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, localhost

As I am running following set of the code

1. AngularJS
   [image]
2. HTML

[image: html code]
 3. Error

[image]

Comment: It's a standard CORS issue.

Comment: @mikep how can we resolve it, would you please like to suggest me what to do?

Comment: @BadshahTracker try blow plugin

Comment: @BadshahTracker worked ? thanks

Comment: @BinitGhetiya yes it worked. I'm thankful to you. But now has every client to install the plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below plugin in chrome browser:
[Core extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en)

And if you want to add on server side then on server you can add below headers (for PHP add this in index.php)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, X-CLIENT-ID, X-CLIENT-SECRET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: thanks. It solved my problem. Now, do I need every of my clients to enable this extension?

Comment: @BadshahTracker no for implementing APIs only (development) purpose only. once you will put your application on server that time your API host and hosted application server both are same so you wont get any error.

Comment: thank you so much. I seriously appreciate your help.

Comment: If your application in under development and you want to show them to all your clients then yes they need to install that.

Comment: @BadshahTracker you are welcome, you can also UP vote the answer :)

Comment: I got what you're trying to explain to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162277/discussion-between-badshah-tracker-and-binit-ghetiya).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, needed to do it on the server side @BinitGhetiya

Answer (score 3):

Installing above mentioned plugin for chrome is not a permanent solution for your issue and you cannot ask the end user to do the same.

Best way to do is to handle it in your api code.

There are plenty of resources available to see how it is configured for various languages api. The following link will make you to understand about it and how to configure.

**[`Why does my JavaScript get a “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” error when Postman does not?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)**

Answer (score 2):

Javascript was designed to not forward from a domain to another.  You're going from localhost to another domain.  There is a relatively new process to do it: Cross Origin Resource Sharing or CORS.  Here, the server and client agree to permit it.  It's done via headers.  You need a CORS header.  Here is a reference:    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS